# How to pass arguments to main.cpp with edit scheme in Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode5

I have this simple code as an example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    int a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c ;
    std::cout << a << " "<< b << " " << c;
}
```

I would like to pass this code the arguments "1 2 3" that are in a text file named file.txt located in the same file as main.

In Product > Edit Schemes I select the Run Argument side bar option followed by the arguments tab. Under "arguments passed on launch" I enter < file.txt select ok and run my program. The program builds and runs but does not pass the arguments "1 2 3" in file.txt. Is there some other setting I'm missing? Am I putting my file in the wrong folder? Would really like to make this work so I can test code on large sets of data that would be annoying to enter manually.

if I cout << argv[1] I get "<" if I don't quote. If I do quote the argument I get "< text.txt."

Comment: There's no shortcut for passing arguments contained in a file to a program.

Comment: Does it work if you have the numbers on their own line?

Comment: @BrianBi Yes there is. Unless we're misunderstanding each other. I can do it in the command line. Just don't want to go back and forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Xcode doesn't directly support command-line file redirections like you're asking for.  The arguments are for setting the `argv` vector in `main`.  When you run a program on the command line, the shell (typically `/bin/bash`) interprets and sets up redirections and doesn't pass those bits to the program as arguments.  XCode doesn't use a shell to launch your program, and doesn't set up the redirection either.

The closest you can get through Xcode, without changing your source code, requires two steps:

1. In your scheme's Run setup, in the Info tab, set the executable to `/bin/sh`. You will need to choose “Other…” from the popup menu to get an Open dialog, then type `/bin/sh`.  When you type `/` in the Open dialog, you will get a popup text box.
2. In the Arguments tab, add this argument:

   ```
   -c "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_PATH < /path/to/text.txt"
   ```

   Replace `/path/to/text.txt` with the path to your input file.

This will run a shell, and ask the shell to run your program with input redirection,  **but** you will find that Xcode ignores your breakpoints, making it hard to debug your program.

Comment: Are you sure? What are the argument options for? Some other posts had people doing it in older versions. For what your suggesting do mean using the pre-script or post-script options. If so which one? I'll give both a shot.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Ok, I get it now. I was thinking perhaps that Xcode used the shell to launch the program. 

The only issue I'm having now is that there is no option for /bin/sh for the executable under the info tab or Run setup.

Comment: Ok, thats what I thought but there is no /bin/sh to be found.

Comment: Every Mac OS X installation has `/bin/sh`, but you cannot get to it by default with the Open dialog box.  You can either type `/` to get a text box popup, or press Command-Shift-. to make the Open dialog show you everything, then navigate to the root directory of your hard drive and from there to `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Ok getting somewhere. But had to do Command-Shift-g to get the goto folder to drop down. Now when I run I get:

/bin/sh: /path/to/text.txt: No such file or directory

Note: I put in my file path not the generic path.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks Rob. I put the infile in my home directory and it worked. I had it in a deep directory and I guess it didn't like that. Sweet, thanks again.